# $(TeamBuildConstants) is blank for TFS builds

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a post build event like this:

> if NOT "$(TeamBuildConstants)"=="_TEAM_BUILD_" "$(SolutionDir)Tools\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)MyAssembly.nuspec" -BasePath "$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)."
>
> if "$(TeamBuildConstants)"=="_TEAM_BUILD_" "$(SolutionDir)Tools\NuGet.exe" pack "$(ProjectDir)MyAssembly.nuspec" -BasePath "$(OutDir)."

When I build on in Visual Studio $(TeamBuildConstants) is blank (as it should be).

But when I build on my TFS 2010 Server, $(TeamBuildConstants) is still blank.  What do I need to do to tell when I have a TFS Build running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Team Build**

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/618392e6-a108-4e70-898b-52ee6afc0600/

> TeamBuild 2008 sets IsDesktopBuild=false for builds run by a build agent. The default (if not set on the command line or by a project property) is true. The TFS 2010 behavior is the same, so try something like:

```
<PostBuildEvent Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)' == 'true' ">echo This is post-build</PostBuildEvent>
```

Although I have heard from some people that it doesn't work, and there is an alternative property - $(BuildingInsideVisualStudio) - which may work instead.

If neither work you may need to edit your Build Definition and customize the msbuild call yourself.

**NuGet 1.6**

NuGet 1.6 also has an msbuild file that can create nuget files which may be worth looking at.

*snippet*

```
<PackageOutputDir Condition="$(PackageOutputDir) == ''">$(TargetDir.Trim('\\'))</PackageOutputDir>
<BuildCommand>"$(NuGetExePath)" pack "$(ProjectPath)" -p Configuration=$(Configuration) -o "$(PackageOutputDir)" -symbols</BuildCommand>
```