# TFS Team Build Isn't Picking Up Post Build Event

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a build issue that I'm hoping you can help me with. An msbuild argument within a post-build event is not getting picked up for some reason. This is the logic for that post-build event:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe 
"$(SolutionDir)SolutionItems\Deploy.proj" 
/v:n /p:ConfigName=$(ConfigurationName) 
/p:ProjName=$(ProjectName) /p:TeamBuildConstants=$(TeamBuildConstants)
```

When the post build event fires, this is returned:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe 
"C:\Builds\41\MyApp\DbScripts\Sources\Source\DbScripts\SolutionItems\Deploy.proj" 
/v:n /p:ConfigName=Release /p:ProjName=DoNotDeploy /p:TeamBuildConstants=
```

Notice that TeamBuildConstants has no value. The only way I can get this to come through is if I hardcode it in the build definition like this:

```
MSBuild Arguments: /p:TeamBuildConstants="_TEAM_BUILD_"
```

This only happens on the build box that is relatively new. The other ones I have are not experiencing this issue. Only thing I can think of is that there is some difference between the build boxes, but I'm not sure what that could be.

Comment: possible duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134004/teambuildconstants-is-blank-for-tfs-builds

Comment: But this post build event works just fine on other build boxes. :/

Comment: Unfortunately, I may have to put a bounty on this, because the issue is not the same as the link above. I have three build boxes and only 1 is exhibiting this behavior. All of the others are perfectly fine.

Comment: 1. What does the post build return on a successful build box?
2. What is the difference between tools on the new build box vs old ones?

Comment: So the msbuild log for the post-build event on the unsuccessful build box looks like this: 

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe 
"C:\Builds\41\MyApp\DbScripts\Sources\Source\DbScripts\SolutionItems\Deploy.proj"/v:n /p:ConfigName=Release /p:ProjName=DoNotDeploy /p:TeamBuildConstants=`

This is what it looks like on a successful box:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe 
"C:\Builds\41\MyApp\DbScripts\Sources\Source\DbScripts\SolutionItems\Deploy.proj"/v:n /p:ConfigName=Release /p:ProjName=DoNotDeploy /p:TeamBuildConstants=_TEAM_BUILD_`

Comment: what about the question number 2?

Comment: I'm working on that one.

Comment: I just noticed a difference, at least in terms of the build activity log. On the build box that is fine, I see this msbuild argument before the TeamBuildConstants one:

`/p:FxCopDir="C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop"`

That's not there on the build agent that doesn't work.

Comment: So VS 2008 is installed on the older build boxes (along with VS2010 and 2012), although, to my knowledge, we do not have any VS 2008 solutions.

Comment: You are using TFS2010? Everything I read about TeamBuilConstants mentions that it doesnt work in Tfs2010, only "$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)=='true'" works in TFS2010.

Comment: Yes, we're on TFS 2010.